# Why is my array reseting the key number?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, foreach, find

i am using this html parser that is searching for HTML elements and printing them on screen as they come up

some are ID some are H4

now the issue is after it finds an ID it looks for a H4

now when i do a for each loop at the end only the H4 are coming up but not the one price

i would like to know why this is happening

i am new and loving PHP but i dont get why the key is reseting and forgeting the ID key

CODE =>

```
<?php 

ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
set_time_limit(0);
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url= "ethicon2.html";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html -> load_file($target_url);

$line = 0;                 
$ref = $html-> find('.price');                  
$ref = $html-> find('h4');              
$ref = $html-> find('h4');

foreach ($ref as $value) {
    print "$value<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why do you keep setting ref? It will only take on the value returned by the last line where you set it.

Comment: so how do i make it take both values?

Comment: Well if find supports CSS: `$ref = $html->find('.price, h4');`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding them into an array like so:

```
$ref[] = $html-> find('.price');                  
$ref[] = $html-> find('h4');              
$ref[] = $html-> find('h4');
```

**EDIT**
If you want these to appear in one array try this

```
$ref2 = array();
foreach($ref as $r)
{
    $ref2 = array_merge($ref2,$r);
}
print_r($ref2);
```

Comment: with your answer gee i get array as the 3 asnwers